# Can I post an image in json request to URL in IFTTT Maker Trigger?

Tags: json, curl, ifttt

Recently, IFTTT introduce its [Channel Maker](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks?utm_medium=Blog&utm_source=Updates&utm_campaign=Maker_Launch&utm_term=&utm_content=). 
You can trigger an action by send post request to a specific URL with a json(three key:value elements).

[image: IFTTT Maker Documentation]

It means by making your own trigger URL, you can easily post { "value1": "your first value", "value2": "your second value", "value3": "your third value" } data to trigger an action.

I have made an Applet to post some text value to the URL and create a note in my Evernote account with those text. To carry this idea further, I want to post images to create notes in Evernote.

So I am wondering if there is a way to send json request **with images**?

Comment: Nope, not directly with the Maker service. Perhaps you could upload the image somewhere (cloud bucket or Imgur) and post the link to it. Not sure if Evernote would import the image from the url link, though.

Comment: @EricCochran Thanks for comment. I have every images url. It seems Evernote wouldn't import the image from url automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the maker service to add filter code which would allow you to pull the image into a stream, then post it that way, not sure, plan on trying soon.