# IFTTT Webhook to Pinterest

Tags: webhooks, pinterest, ifttt

I am trying to post an image to a Pinterest board via a webhook (Maker service), but every time I try I get a *success* response, but in IFTTT on actions, I see a *Applet failed: There was a problem with the Pinterest service* message. What can be wrong? The images I try to post are hosted on my own server.

```
function pinterest_post(image, description, boards) {
request({
    url: 'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/pinterest_post/with/key/*******-***********-*',
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        "value1": boards,
        "value2": image,
        "value3": description
    }
}, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
    } else if (response.body.error) {
        console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you can't send images which are multiform data to pinterest webhook. I'm trying to figure out how to do this right now myself. I don't believe you can do it though, see this post: [Can I post an image in json request to URL in IFTTT Maker Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351030/can-i-post-an-image-in-json-request-to-url-in-ifttt-maker-trigger?rq=1)